# rails ransack checkbox error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have this view

```
- f.checks :membership_cancelled_true , [["canceled membership", true] ], :class => 'checkboxy' do |check|
          = check.box
          = check.label
```

I use with MetaSearch gem and It works well but now I upgraded rails to 4.0 and I have to use Ransack gem(Which is the new version of MetaSearch) and this check box does not work.

This is the error:

```
undefined method `checks' for #<Ransack::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xb42f015c>
```

Comment: its not recognizing checks.. is this proper syntax? check the docs. check_box_tag?

Answer (score 3):

`Ransack::Helpers::FormBuilder` inherits from `::ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder`.  It doesn't provide a `checks` method like `MetaSearch::Helpers::FormBuilder` did.  MetaSearch's `checks` method built a set of `check_box_tag` and `label_tag` values.

In Ransack, for a single checkbox condition like the one you included in the question, we can just do something like this:

```
<%= f.check_box :membership_cancelled_true %>
<%= f.label :membership_cancelled_true %>
```

For a multiple checkbox condition, where we want to include all records where an attribute matches any of a set of checked values, we can do something like this:

```
<% predicate = "my_attribute_in" %>
<% { "Value One" => "1", "Value Two" => "2", "Value Three" => "3"}.each do |label, value| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "q[#{predicate}][]", value, params.try(:[],:q).try(:[],predicate).try(:include?, value), id: "q_#{predicate}_#{value}" %>
  <%= label_tag "q_#{predicate}_#{value}", label %><br />
<% end %>
```